# Difference between let and apply on returned object

Tags: kotlin

Here is the code I use to dismiss existing fragment. I am able to use `let` and `apply`.
I read a lot about differences between `let` and `apply` and I understood that:

- apply modifies existing object that we have
- let creates copy of the object and can modify it. If we exit out of `let` scope the original object is intact. Am I right?

My code is presented in two versions.

```
private fun prepareQuestionFragment(indexOfMarkerList: Int): QuestionFragment {
    childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(QuestionFragment.TAG)?.apply {
        this as QuestionFragment
        this.dismissAllowingStateLoss()
    }

    return QuestionFragment.newInstance(indexOfMarkerList)
}   

private fun prepareQuestionFragment(indexOfMarkerList: Int): QuestionFragment {
    childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(QuestionFragment.TAG)?.let {
        it as QuestionFragment
        it.dismissAllowingStateLoss()
    }

    return QuestionFragment.newInstance(indexOfMarkerList)
}
```

What is the difference at this case? For me they behaves the same.

Does the `let` make a copy of Fragment? If so, we would dismiss copy of fragment and the the original one should stay visible. Am I missing something? Does `let` and `apply` contains still reference to the object (not copy)?

Answer (score 4):

> let creates copy of the object and can modify it. If we exit out of let scope the original object is intact. Am I right?

No. Java/Kotlin doesn't have a generic concept of copying objects. They can only copy references to the same object.

The main difference in your example is how lambda receives `QuestionFragment` object. Lambda in `let()` gets `QuestionFragment` as its regular argument, by default named as `it`. Lambda in `apply()` receives this object as its receiver argument, so `this`. It's almost a cosmetic difference, it doesn't really differ in the way how it works.

Another difference is that `let()` returns the result of the lambda, so in your example the result of `dismissAllowingStateLoss()`. `apply()` returns the receiver object, so the result of `findFragmentByTag()`. You don't use the return value of `let()`/`apply()`, so this difference is irrelevant in your example.